# How to summarize a long text using GPT-3

Tags: gpt, automatic-summarization

What is the best way to summarize a long text that exceeds 4096 token limit (like a podcast transcript for example)? As I understand I need to split the text into chunks to summarize, and then concatenate the results and summarize those. Is there already a popular open-source script to do that?

Do I understand correctly that GPT-3 is the best model to do that? I've seen some articles about extractive summarization using BERT but the results were pretty low quality.

Comment: I think GPT-3 can only be accessed through an API currently.

Comment: @lynx and https://beta.openai.com/playground

Comment: @lynx both API and Playground don't support texts larger than 4096 tokens

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there already a popular open-source script to do that?

The Python library [GPT Index](https://github.com/jerryjliu/gpt_index) (MIT license) can summarize a large document or collection of documents with GPT-3.

From the [documentation](https://gpt-index.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guides/use_cases.html#use-case-summarization-over-documents):

> ```
> index = GPTTreeIndex(documents)
> response = index.query("<summarization_query>", mode="summarize")
> ```
>
> The “default” mode for a tree-based query is traversing from the top of the graph down to leaf nodes. For summarization purposes we will want to use `mode="summarize"`.
>
> A summarization query could look like one of the following:
>
> - “What is a summary of this collection of text?”
> - “Give me a summary of person X’s experience with the company.”

The documentation includes a notebook with complete examples: https://github.com/jerryjliu/gpt_index/blob/main/examples/paul_graham_essay/TestEssay.ipynb

---

Another Python library: https://github.com/hwchase17/langchain (MIT license). From the [documentation](https://langchain.readthedocs.io/en/latest/use_cases/summarization.html):

```
from langchain.chains.summarize import load_summarize_chain
chain = load_summarize_chain(llm, chain_type="map_reduce")
chain.run(docs)
```

FYI {1,2} are two great papers looking at GPT-3 performance for summarization, but they only looked at short texts.

Update 2023-02-23: the next version of GPT may allow 32k tokens:

[image]

---

Update 2023-11-15: Interesting leaderboard for summarization of relatively short documents: https://github.com/vectara/hallucination-leaderboard

[image]

---

References:

- {1} Goyal, Tanya, Junyi Jessy Li, and Greg Durrett. "[News Summarization and Evaluation in the Era of GPT-3.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2209.12356.pdf)" arXiv preprint arXiv:2209.12356 (2022).
- {2} Tianyi Zhang, Faisal Ladhak, Esin Durmus, Percy Liang, Kathleen McKeown, Tatsunori B. Hashimoto. [Benchmarking Large Language Models for News Summarization](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2301.13848.pdf). arXiv:2301.13848.